# What are the corresponding registers in aarch64 compared with x86_64?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, arm64, unwind

I have a piece of code that performs unwind in x86_64, I am trying to step forward in c code like this:

```
frame->rsp = frame->rbp+2;
frame->rip = *(frame->rbp+1);
frame->rbp = *frame->rbp;
```

However, I don't know if this is correct in the situation of aarch64.
I found aarch64 have x29(fp), x30(lr), and SP.
Are they same to bp, ip and sp?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: ARM's "ip" isn't the instruction pointer.  For that you want PC, the program counter.  Also no, LR (the link register) is not the frame pointer (rBP), it's the return address (which x86-64 keeps on the stack.)

Comment: thank, I want to perform step forward(aka: up unwinding) just like what we do in x86_64, but I can't figure out how. Could you please help further? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Just like on x86-64, debuggers should know how to read the metadata (e.g. from the `.eh_frame` DWARF metadata in ELF executables) that tells it how to unwind the stack in normal builds (`-fomit-frame-pointer` is on at `-O1` and higher in GCC).  `frame 1` vs. `frame 0` should work in GDB.  And other commands like `bt full`.